# apt-get install terminating because of matlab-support

Tags: linux, git, matlab, ubuntu

Two days ago I installed Matlab on my Ubuntu 14.04 and I run

```
apt-get matlab-support
```

from my terminal, but I could not finish it successfully because it requires the path for my Matlab installation and I gave it but it gives error, so I leave this and quit.

But now I face serious issue whenever I run any command on my terminal regarding `apt-get` like `apt-get install git`.

It gives pop-ups the Matlab support installation error on my terminal.
I am stuck it did not install any software.

Comment: Can you paste actual error from terminal?

Comment: its a GUI screen which requires actual installation path of Matlab, but I could not resolve it and quite Matlab support, but now I want to install Git and it also gives me same Gui error which requires Matlab installation path, I don't know why it requires, I think something is in my apt-get pipeline, if I restart this apt-get may be it resolve it I don't know how and I restart my computer many times

Comment: Does `apt-get remove matlab-support` fix this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: yes I fix this by giving the required path of my Matlab installation, everything is fine now,thanks